# How to prevent MUI React Menu component moving scrollbar to top when clicked?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have an ellipsis menu which display several options when opened. When I click the ellipsis icon, my view's scrollbar moves to top of the screen. How to disable this?

```
<IconButton
    aria-label="more"
    aria-controls={open ? 'long-menu' : null}
    aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : null}
    aria-haspopup="true"
    onClick={handleClick}
  >
    <MoreVertIcon style={{ fontSize: '27px', color: 'black' }} />
  </IconButton>
  <Menu
    MenuListProps={{
      'aria-labelledby': 'long-button',
    }}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    PaperProps={{
      style: {
        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
        width: '31ch',
      },
    }}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem
        key={option.name}
        onClick={() => {
          option.onClick();
          handleClose();
        }}
        style={{ fontSize: '13px' }}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={option.icon} style={{ fontSize: '12px' }} />
        <MenuItemText>{option.name}</MenuItemText>
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Menu>
```